# PHP how to access files in a folder protected by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an uploads folder which is protected with htaccess file from public access:

```
deny from all
```

However I want to access this folder within my admin panel (using PHP) to show for example profile pictures of users.

How is it possible? Can I simply include the files?

Update :
to describe the situation a bit more accurate, I want to show profile pictures of users using `img` tag, which tries to access pictures from browser and gets blocked. what should I put in src attribite?

Comment: Sure. Htaccess denies the access via browser (or at least http/https ports). PHP is working on the server itself, it has no influence. You can include files from the protected folder.

Comment: Sometimes the best approach is to just do the thing and see what happens.

Comment: If nobody is supposed to publicly access that folder, why is it in your web server's document root to begin with? Put it someplace else…

Comment: Because this is a sort of script that I should install everyday on different servers with different folder structures. In this way all the script related files are in one single folder and sensitive data are also protected by htaccess. This makes it easier to install the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it using php. I created a php file `image.php` :

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('path to protected image');
```

Then I used `image.php` as `src` attribute of `img`.

Comment: You're also making sure you're doing some sort of authentication there, right? If this script will output the image for any and all users, you've just created your own backdoor…

Comment: Yeah sure, users should be logged in to access image.php.